# Symfony 2: Accessing a firewalled route with two separate providers

Tags: symfony, url-routing

We have a system where the administrators and standard users are handled by their own separate security providers. This has caused a problem in the administrative pages because the administrators can't access any files or images that are behind the main site's firewall unless they are also signed in to the main site.

The images and files need to be accessible to all authenticated users and administrators, regardless of provider. They are served through a controller that provides more fine grained access control.

Is it possible to define more than one provider to allow access to a route?

Here's a stripped down version of our current security.yml:

```
security:
    providers:
        admin_user_db:
            entity: { class: OurAdminUserBundle:AdminUser, property: username }
        site_user_db:
            entity: { class: OurSiteUserBundle:SiteUser, property: username }
    firewalls:
        admin_login:
            pattern:  ^/admin/login$
            security: false
        site_user_login:
            pattern: ^/login
            security: false
        file_route:
            pattern: ^/file
            anonymous: ~
            ### We need to allow this route only for authorized users from
            ### either admin_user_db or site_user_db providers
        admin_secured_area:
            pattern: ^/admin
            http_basic: ~
            provider: admin_user_db
            form_login:
                check_path: /admin/login_check
                login_path: /admin/login
            logout:
                path:   /admin/logout
                target: /
        site_secured_area:
            pattern: .*
            http_basic: ~
            provider: site_user_db
            form_login:
                check_path: /check_login
                login_path: /login
                failure_path: /login
                failure_forward: false
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess what you looking for is `ChainProvider`. This provider will be configured to use your two current providers in a sequential way.

The chain provider will first try to authenticate the user with the first provider it was configured with. If it's a success, the user is authenticated. If it's a failure, the chain provider will try the next one and so on until no more providers can be tried.

I used this technique to let users authenticate with either form login or facebook login. I had two providers, one for facebook, one for form. Then, in my firewall, the provider was the chain provider and then, users were able to login with their credentials or with their facebook account.

Since chain provider is sequential, what I suggest is to put the provider that will probably by used most often first.

Here a configuration sample taken from the Symfony documentation site:

```
security:
    providers:
        chain_provider:
            chain:
                providers: [in_memory, user_db]
        in_memory:
            users:
                foo: { password: test }
        user_db:
            entity: { class: Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User, property: username
```

You can take a look at the documenation here:

1. [Using Multiple User Providers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#using-multiple-user-providers)

Regards,
Matt

Comment: Thank you for the answer, we were able to set up the `ChainProvider` with these instructions (although I think the syntax was a bit different in our version of Symfony). Ultimately we ended up ditching the `AdminUser` and using roles instead like @jperovic suggests, since we realized the separate providers aren't really necessary in our scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I had some experience with this issue and the solution was the one that **Matt** wrote.

However, since out application had Administration, Student and Teacher firewalls I couldn't achieve successful impersonation when needed. That is, users from Administration could impersonate users from their firewall and those only.

Now, it is possible that I did something wrong but because this was time sensitive task we decided to put everything behind single firewall and let the different **roles** do the job. This turned out to be much simpler solution but ultimately it's up to you...